# Is it bad design to use dynamic_cast in c++

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I have a class CAbstractNode and it has 5 derived classes

out of 5, only 2 (special) need a method  SetValue() and a member int nVal;

```
//myFunction is virtual function of base(cAbstractNode) implemented in 2 special derived classes
myFunction(CAbstractNode * obj, int val)
{
    Derived_02 nodeObj = dynamic_cast<Derived_02*>(obj);

    if(res != NULL)
    {
        nodeObj->setValue(val);
    }

    //remaining code goes here...
}


//myFunction is virtual function implemented in remaining 3 derived classes ( setValue() is not needed here)
myFunction(CAbstractNode * obj, int val)
{

    //remaining code goes here...
}
```

shall I go with dynamic cast for 2 derived classes (as shown above)

or

shall I take setValue() method as virtual in base(CAbstractNode)
and implement in 2 derived classes and this method keeping empty in other 3 derived classes ?

Comment: `dynamic_cast` should be avoided in favor of virtual functions.

Comment: Yes, using dynamic cast to switch on types is bad design.

Comment: Also want to add `std::variant` as a possible replacement. You don't always want this functionality contained within the class.

Comment: The $3.62 question is, if only some children need or can use this function, why should your code that deals with the parent class know about it? Perhaps *this* is the real bad design decision. Ugly workarounds like empty methods or dynamic casts are only the consequence. Or rather the very existence of said function is bad design. Setters (and pointers) are best used when hunting fowl. An interface should be defined in terms of what the class *does*, not what it *has*.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is not `dynamic_cast` itself, it is a symptom. In your case if `myFunction` accepts `CAbstractNode` interface it should work with it. But for whatever reason it has to know about `Derived_02` and call specific method of that, which most probably shows that `CAbstractNode` interface is poorly designed. Or at least not properly designed, but it is up to you to decide if you want to fix interface or keep workaround. Remember engineering is mostly about compromises, perfect design quite often is not reachable or not practical.

Answer (score 0):

`dynamic_cast` is a *[code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)*

Usually this can be solved overloading the functions or using virtual functions.

Comment: In deep hierarchies creating virtual methods to avoid type checking will result in violation of SRP in the base class. I do not mean SRP must be perfectly followed, I just mean your base class will contain dozens of unrelated methods.